# Change image associated with Google API App

Tags: google-developers-console

I have rebranded my website and as a result the icon that is associated with my Google API app is now obsolete:

[image: Google App]

I can't find anywhere in the Google Developer Console to choose a new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to the **Credentials** page:

[image: Credentials]

Then click on the **OAuth consent screen** tab:

[image: OAuth consent screen]

Finally, you can specify the URL to the logo:

[image: Product logo URL]